# WPF listview item that binds to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I know this question may have been asked before but I can't find a solution for my problem and I will need some help.

What I want to accomplish :

I want to bind the exposed property **`Values`** of each item (`ParameterValues`) in my `ListView` to the `ComboBox` column and have the exposed property **`SelectedValue`** as selected item.

What I have done:

```
public class MyViewModel : MvvmTemplate //MvvmTemplate implements InotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<ParameterValues> _parameterValuesTest;

    public ObservableCollection<ParameterValues> ParameterValuesTest
    {
        get => _parameterValuesTest;
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                return;
            _parameterValuesTest = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(); 
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Parameters = new List<ParametersModel>(GetParametersFromDatabase());
        ParameterValuesTest = new ObservableCollection<ParameterValues>();
        ParameterValuesTest.Clear();
        foreach(var param in parameters)
        {
            ParameterValuesTest.Add(new ParameterValues(param));
        }
    }
}
```

Parameters model :

```
public class ParametersModel:MvvmTemplate
{
    public ParametersModel()
    {
        Parameters = new Parameters();
    }

    public ParametersModel(Parameters Parameters)
    {
        Parameters = Parameters;
    }


    public Parameters Parameters { get; set; }

    public int Id
    {
        get => Parameters.Id;
        set
        {
            if (Parameters.Id == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            Parameters.Id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    
    
    public string Value1
    {
        get => Parameters.Value1;
        set
        {
            if (Parameters.Value1 == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            Parameters.Value1 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
        
    public string Value2
    {
        get => Parameters.Value2;
        set
        {
            if (Parameters.Value2 == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            Parameters.Value2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Parameters values model :

```
public class ParameterValues:MvvmTemplate
{
    public ParameterValues(ParametersModel parameter)
    {
        ParametersModel = parameter;
        Values = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "Default Value",
            ParametersModel.Value1,
            ParametersModel.Value2
        };
    
        SelectedValue = Values.First();
    }


    public ParametersModel ParametersModel { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _values;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Values
    {
        get => _values;
        set
        {
            if (_values == value)
                return;
            _values = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _selectedValue;

    public string SelectedValue
    {
        get => _selectedValue;
        set
        {
            if (_selectedValue == value)
                return;
            _selectedValue = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParameterValuesTest}">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ParametersModel.Id}"/>
         <GridViewColumn  Header="Value">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <Grid>
                     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" DisplayMemberPath="SelectedValue" Height="0"/>
                     <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" DisplayMemberPath="SelectedValue" SelectedValuePath="SelectedValue" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}" TextSearch.TextPath="SelectedValue" Text="{Binding SelectedValue}" IsEditable="True"/>
                  </Grid>
               </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` are supposed to denote the names of properties of the item class. No idea why you think a string should have a `SelectedValue` property. Remove these assignments and replace `SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"` with `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue}"`. Also remove `TextSearch.TextPath="SelectedValue"` and `Text="{Binding SelectedValue}"`.

Comment: @Ciemens Thank you for clarifying things for me. I removed these and it worked. I will accept thatguy's answer since this is the one i followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code.

- In the parameters model, the assignment does not work, correct the parameter name.

  ```
  public ParametersModel(Parameters parameters)
  {
     Parameters = parameters;
  }
  ```
- Remove the `ItemsControl` from the `Grid`, as it is hidden by the `ComboBox` or integrate it differently if you really need it, e.g. create rows or columns and place the controls in there.
- The bindings in the `ComboBox` are wrong, you should bind to `SelectedItem` instead of using `SelectedValue`, since you have a collection of `string`s and not of a type that contains other properties that you want to bind to.

  ```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue}" Text="{Binding SelectedValue}" IsEditable="True"/>
  ```
- Remove the `TextSearch` attached property, as it is not used here.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me.
The assignment works in my actual code i used examples and actual XAML the problem was the binding.